# How to update a cell value based on other cell values in excel

Tags: excel, vba

In the attached spreadsheet ( Sales Analysis Report), I would like to update column H value automatically by using below fields.
[image]

[image]

[image]
**Sales:D column** , **Sales:H column** , **Payments Receieved:D column** and **Payments Receieved:H column**

Can you please guide me how we can achieve this either through macro (VBA code) (or) we can do this in a simple formula as well.

I have highlighted all the cells which are required for this logic in color.

Thanks in advance for your time and appreciated your help.

Regards,
Narry

Comment: Bryan, I missed to add the attachments. I have just added the attachment. Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No VBA needed here, Narry.

Enter this formula in cell `H1` of Customer Information tab:

`=SUMIF(Sales!D:D,D1,Sales!H:H)-SUMIF('Payments Recieved'!D:D,D1,'Payments Recieved'!H:H)`

Then drag down to fit the other rows.

You can easily google 'vlookup' or look in Excel Help to find out more about what it does.

Comment: Scott, The requirement I have here is not straightforward as this is tied to customer code number . For each customer code number, there will be only 1 entry in customer information (1 screen shot). Then I need to sum the invoice amount for a customer in Sales sheet and deduct the sum of payments received for the same customer. ( Please observe customer code number KDP1 in all the sheets)... Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Narry -> please see my edited answer. This should get you what you need. Just a different formula :)

Comment: Scott, This formula is not working for my requirement because below logic is missing in the formula: For Example, KDP1 in customer information sheet has 2 entries in Sales sheet ( Row D2:H2 AND D5:H5); Similarly in Payments sheet, we have 2 entries (D1:H1 and D3:H3);        The correct value for H1 in customer information sheet should be as follows: H1 Value = [(D2:H2) + (D5:H5)] - [(D1:H1) + (D3:H3)].... I am able to explain logic for one example, this way it should work for all other cells.. That is where I need your expertise.. Thanks again for your time.. Narry

Comment: @Narry -> The `SUMIF` formula does just that. It will sum all the values in Col H of the Sales sheet where column D = DKP1 (or whatever value you have), and then do the same for the Payments sheet, and then subtract the two. If you need something different than this, please explain again. Or perhaps, read up on `SUMIF` ...

Comment: Scott, I have gone through sumif function and understood to some extent; The formula you have provided me is not giving correct values as per sales and payments sheet data. I don't see any place for sending the excel spreadsheet to you in this site. Please let me know how I can share the sheet..

Comment: @Narry -> you can upload to www.dropbox.com or a similar site for me to download.

Comment: Scott,Please find below URL to download the excel sheet and the related details:                                     https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_giPP7HzohAQ3dzUm9ycFBoVk0

Comment: @Narry -> do you expect the result for KDP1 to be $113,000 (`9,750+117,750 = 127,500` - `4,500+10,000 = 14500` = **113,000**) in the Customers Information tab?

Comment: Scott, The result for KDP1 should be (9,750+17,750 = 27,500 - 4,500+10,000 = 14500 >> 13,000) in the customer information tab. The same logic should be applied for Complete H coloumn in customer information tab.. Thanks a lot for your time....

Comment: @Narry -> Okay, so I misread one of the numbers, but got the same results, with an extra 1 in front of the number. The `SUMIF` formula above is the **EXACT** answer you need. Do you try implementing it?

Comment: Scott, There was a small correction in the formula.. It was starting from D1 instead of D2.. I have modified that and it started working absolutely fine.. Thank you so much for helping me on this....       =SUMIF(Sales!D:D,D2,Sales!H:H)-SUMIF('Payments Recieved'!D:D,D2,'Payments Recieved'!H:H)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want Column H to be Col. G and Col. F multiplied. If this is correct then a simple formula will work.

In H1 type `=F1 * G1`

Copy this cell. Select the rest of the cells in H that need the formula, and paste.

Comment: Bryan,  I would like to update column H value automatically by using below fields. Sales:D column , Sales:H column , Payments Receieved:D column and Payments Receieved:H column. Please refer to the attached screenshots for complete understanding.